# make a post request to API with http in flutter

Tags: api, http, post, flutter

i want to make http post request to api, i using http.post with flutter:

```
class SignUpApiProvider {
  Client client = Client();
  final host = Setting.host + 'signup';

  Future signUp(String name, String email, String password) async {
    final res = await client
        .post(host, body:{'name': name, 'email': email, 'password': password});
    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
     return res;
    } else {
      return throw Exception('Failed to add data');
    }
  }
}
```

and when make request give me this error:

```
E/flutter (17691): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: Exception: Failed to add data
E/flutter (17691): #0      SignUpApiProvider.signUp (package:mosul/src/resources/SignupApiProvider.dart:19:14)
E/flutter (17691): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (17691): #1      Repository.signUp (package:mosul/src/resources/repository.dart:14:83)
E/flutter (17691): #2      SignUpState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:mosul/src/ui/users/signup.dart:66:34)
E/flutter (17691): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (17691): #3      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:513:14)
E/flutter (17691): #4      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:568:30)
E/flutter (17691): #5      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:120:24)
E/flutter (17691): #6      TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:242:9)
E/flutter (17691): #7      TapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:204:7)
E/flutter (17691): #8      GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:156:27)
E/flutter (17691): #9      _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:218:20)
E/flutter (17691): #10     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:192:22)
E/flutter (17691): #11     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:149:7)
E/flutter (17691): #12     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:101:7)
E/flutter (17691): #13     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:85:7)
E/flutter (17691): #14     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1136:13)
E/flutter (17691): #15     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
E/flutter (17691): #16     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:931:7)
E/flutter (17691): #17     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:223:10)
E/flutter (17691): #18     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:144:5)
E/flutter (17691):
```

when i try to make request by using Postman it is working good, thank you very much

edit: when i print (res.body) in else section :

```
{"message":"cannot create user!!"}
E/flutter ( 3026): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: Exception: Failed to add data
.............
```

it is from server
....
but it postman it is work :(
[image]

Comment: What is printed if you add `print(res.body);` to your else{} clause? The only thing you know for sure is that you are returning your Exception but it will be useful to know which statusCode is returned when it is not 200. Otherwise we only know it did not succeed.

Comment: Thank you, i will try later and show you the result :)

Comment: see my Edit, when print (res.body)

Comment: Do you have anything in your headers in Postman and is that equivalent to what is in your `Settings.host`? And where do you return `"message":"cannot create user!!"`?

Comment: just some of header are auto-generated by postman

Comment: You haven't provided a token in Postman or anything? And, where du you return the message? What is determining the outcome?

Comment: no it is for signup, i don't use token, no i dont provide anything :(, and if i understand you, there is no outcome, just data should be inserted in database